# Apache Velocity 2.0 Scripting Compilable not working

Tags: java, velocity, scripting-language, jsr233, apache-velocity

I'm trying to check velocity scripting engine 2.0 which Provide JSR 223 implementation and [support of Compilable](http://velocity.apache.org/news.html)

> the Compilable interface has been implemented in the process.

I use  jars: velocity-engine-scripting-2.0.jar, velocity-1.7.jar, commons-collections-3.2.2.jar

from [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708631/jmeter-script-engine-which-allow-caching-and-compilation) I use the following code

```
//class org.apache.velocity.script.VelocityScriptEngine
final ScriptEngine engine = engineFactory.getScriptEngine();
        if (engine instanceof Compilable) {
            try {
                ((Compilable) engine).compile("");
 ...
```

For velocity I get the following:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: No template name provided
    at org.apache.velocity.script.VelocityScriptEngine.compile(VelocityScriptEngine.java:311)
    at org.apache.velocity.script.VelocityScriptEngine.compile(VelocityScriptEngine.java:288)
    at com.Workers.LevelCheck.main(LevelCheck.java:69)
Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: No template name provided
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.StringResourceLoader.getResourceStream(StringResourceLoader.java:353)
    at org.apache.velocity.Template.process(Template.java:108)
    at org.apache.velocity.script.VelocityScriptEngine.compile(VelocityScriptEngine.java:306)
    ... 2 more
```

Also when I tried to give template name `((Compilable) engine).compile("v.vm");` it failed with same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use velocity-engine-scripting-2.0.jar with velocity-1.7.jar, you need to use velocity-engine-core-2.0.jar otherwise you'll get unpredictable results.

Comment: Velocity uses slf4j, which lets the user choose the output of the log by choosing which [slf4j binding](https://www.slf4j.org/) he puts in the classpath. For instance, you can add slf4j-simple to the classpath, which wlil log by default to stderr.