# Apache Velocity - Failed to eval script due to slf4j dependencies

Tags: java, slf4j, velocity, jsr233, apache-velocity

Continue [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714690/apache-velocity-2-0-scripting-compilable-not-working) question I'm failing to execute scripting in velocity 2.0,

I use jars: **velocity-engine-scripting-2.0.jar**, **velocity-engine-scripting-2.0.jar**, **commons-collections-3.2.2.jar**

I'm trying to follow [developer guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/developer-guide.html#velocity-scripting) example:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
manager.registerEngineName("velocity", new VelocityScriptEngineFactory());
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("velocity");


System.setProperty(VelocityScriptEngine.VELOCITY_PROPERTIES, "path/to/velocity.properties");
String script = "Hello $world";
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
engine.getContext().setWriter(writer);
Object result = engine.eval(script);
System.out.println(writer);
```

I'm getting `slf4j` error when init, I'm using **slf4j-jdk14.jar**. I didn't find solution fir this specific error even after adding `slf4j-api-1.8.0-alpha2.jar`

```
class org.apache.velocity.script.VelocityScriptEngine
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:233)
    at org.apache.velocity.script.VelocityScriptEngine.initVelocityEngine(VelocityScriptEngine.java:212)
    at org.apache.velocity.script.VelocityScriptEngine.compile(VelocityScriptEngine.java:299)
    at org.apache.velocity.script.VelocityScriptEngine.compile(VelocityScriptEngine.java:288)
```

- Notice I **don't use any logging** in my class so I don't need any migration to `slf4j`.

**EDIT 1:**

I found interesting comment in [slf4j FAQ](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html) about Velocity:

> The logging strategy adopted by the Velocity project is a good example
>   of the "custom logging abstraction" anti-pattern. By adopting an
>   independent logging abstraction strategy, Velocity developers have
>   made life harder for themselves, but more importantly, they made life
>   harder for their users.

**EDIT 2:**

Velocity [dependencies](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/dependencies.html) in Runtime are: slf4j-api 1.7.25 and commons-lang 3.5 which I added to classpath but still same error

Comment: This error clearly saying dependency mismatch . IMO if you are using maven project you can exclude the `slf4` version from velocity.

Comment: I'm not in maven project and velocity is calling slf4j specifically so it can't be removed `org.slf4j.Logger.trace`

Comment: I came across this issue specifically i can manage to fix by exclude . I really don't have idea . if you are not using maven. But definitely you must remove that dependency somehow otherwise will not work IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation excerpt you found in the FAQ is clearly outdated.

The [dependencies](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/dependencies.html) page clearly states that while slf4j-api is needed at compile and runtime, you also need to choose one of the slf4j bindings, for instance slf4j-simple which will log to stderr by default.

Comment: I added `slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar` but still same issue

Comment: Did you compile Velocity yourself from the sources? I ran your code without any problem (except it's `VELOCITY_PROPERTIES_KEY`). Maybe you forgot to recompile after changing the libs.