# Is there any way to pass the values in next request based on condition is true in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am looking for a example where i have to verify results in previous response and if condition true have to send one set of values in next request.

Ex

`If(formtype==1)
{`

`send 1 value in next request for 1 of the body value`
}

`if(formtype==2)`

`{ send 2 value in next request for 1 of the body value`

`}`

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditional handlers using JMeter Post or Pre-Processors. For example, I use JSON Extractor to get response data stored in FORM_DATA and combined with JSR223 PostProcessor Javascript.

```
...
var formData = JSON.parse(vars.get("FORM_DATA"));
var formtype = formData.formtype;

if(formtype == 1) {
    log.info("data_next_req" + data_next_req);

    // SET vars
    vars.put("DATA_NEXT_REQ", data_next_req);

} else if (formtype == 2){
    log.info("data_next_req_1" + data_next_req_1);
    log.info("data_next_req_2" + data_next_req_2);

    // SET vars
    vars.put("DATA_NEXT_REQ_1", data_next_req_1);
    vars.put("DATA_NEXT_REQ_2", data_next_req_2);
}
```

Then, on the next request, you can get the value by ${vars-name}.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for response,i tried and extracted data,but when i am sending(${vars-name}) still data not passing into next request

Comment: ```var formData = JSON.parse(vars.get("${form}"));
var formtype = formData.form_type;

if(formtype == 3) {
    vars.put("rooms", [
           {
               "idx": 1,
               "paxes": [
                   {
                       "title": "Mr",
                       "first_name": "Do",
                       "last_name": "Anh",
                       "age": 30,
                       "type": "adult",
                   "nationality": "VN" }]);```

Comment: and used ${rooms} in my next request.```{
  "prebook_id": "${requestid}",
  "source_id": "${sourceid}",
  "adults_count": 1,
  "child_count": 0,
  "child_ages": [],
  "rooms_count": 1,
  "rooms": ${rooms}```

Comment: In post / pre processor you can print logs to make sure the result is correct before putting in variables of Jmeter.

With the syntax: `vars.put ("varName", value);`. Get the value: `vars.get ("varName") `or `$ {"varName"}`. Note when using `vars.get` and `$`, see more at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46418275/9488752

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the `formtype` value using a suitable JMeter's [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (for HTML response types the most appropriate one would be [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/)) and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

As the result you will have i.e. `${formtype}` JMeter Variable with the value of `1`, `2` or whatever is the value of this attribute, the variable can be used directly in the next (and further) requests

The whole process is known as [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) and there is a lot of information about it over the web.