# Why ${var} and vars.get('var') didn't return same value?

Tags: jmeter

Can you please explain me why I get two different result with the same variable?

**Code**

```
def sql_req = "select message from messages where message_timestamp like '" + vars.get('todayDate') + "%' and message_content like '" + vars.get('msg_id') + "%'"

log.info('Req 1 : ' + sql_req)

log.info("Req 2 : select message from messages where message_timestamp like '${todayDate}%' and message_content like '${msg_id}%'")
```

**Result**

```
Req 1 : select message from messages where message_timestamp like '16/06/20%' and message_content like '132656787653545454%'
Req 2 : select message from messages where message_timestamp like '16/06/20%' and message_content like '878765654556467677%'
```

I have several loops setup in the `Thread Group`. But `${msg_id}` keep the value of the first loop. It is not updated ...

So I'm blocked because I want to use this request ( `select message from messages where message_timestamp like '${todayDate}%' and message_content like '${msg_id}%'` ) in a `JDBC Request` but as value is never updated same request is executed every loop.

Can you explain me why ? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418275/jmeter-when-not-to-use-cache-compiled-script-if-available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance.
>
> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as **caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

So either put your `${msg_id}` into "Parameters" section and reference it as `Parameters` or `args[0]` where required:

[image]

Or use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in current thread's scope. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details if needed