# Java Engine Script which support Compilable

Tags: java, groovy, scripting, jsr223

In continuing my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708631/jmeter-script-engine-which-allow-caching-and-compilation), Java uses Beanshell as script engine,
while BeanShell Engine Script Compilable is not supported.

Why java doesn't have script engine other than Beanshell that support Compilable ? can/should we override it? is there an enhancement on this issue?

[Compilable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/Compilable.html):

> compile scripts to a form that can be executed repeatedly without recompilation

I found implementation as [JavaScriptEngine](http://book2s.com/java/src/package/com/l2jserver/commons/javaengine/javascriptengine.html) and [other JavaScriptEngine](http://book2s.com/java/src/package/com/sun/script/java/javascriptengine.html) but I don't know if it's relevant to use.

Does java intentionally let Groovy implement it and thus become the expected scripting language to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a complete answer, but worth mention beanshell2 project,

I found [beanshell2 issue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/beanshell2/issues/43) to support Compilable
There's a fix that can be [download](https://code.google.com/archive/p/beanshell2/downloads) since version bsh-2.1b4.jar

- There's also latest bsh-2.1.6.jar
- There should be 2.1.8 version according to [beanshell2](https://code.google.com/archive/p/beanshell2/)

> Feb. 20, 2014
>
> Update v2.1.8

Also latest Beanshell 2.0b5 (or 2.0b6) support Compilabe but it `throw new Error("unimplemented");`

**EDIT**:

[New issue](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell/issues/52) for implementing Compilabe in Beanshell 2.0